# While not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to write a code, and I want to ask you how can I ask a while loop to repeat untill it finds a word, in my case **END** on the list, for example.

```
L=[]
while "END" (not) in L :
   L=L.append(something)
```

Ask me if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: Why should `END` suddenly appear in `L`? Where does `something` come from?

Comment: @Tichodroma That something may contain END.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? L=[] ... while something != 'END': L.append(something)

Comment: while not "END" in L = type error

Comment: I'm not sure what people think is wrong with this question.  The OP has a clearly stated goal and a piece of non-functional code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code as written will work fine, except that `list.append()` returns None, and modifies the list in place; don't assign it back to L:

```
L=[]
while "END" not in L :
   L.append(something)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> while 12 not in a:
...  a.append(len(a)+1)
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

For example ...

Comment: +1 for correctly parsing the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of somethings this is how you could achieve the desired result.

```
for something in somethings:
    if something != "END":
        L.append(something)
```